# Use files with different encoding on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I have a website hompage encoded on iso-8859-1.
Then into that website i include different css and javascript files encoded on utf-8.
There is a way for show correct characters into the page from js files without change all encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be an issue. You've probably failed to identify the encoding of some of the files. To be on the safe side:

1. Configure your web server to add a correct `Content-Type` HTTP header with a `charset` attribute, e.g.:

   ```
   Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
   ```
2. When the language supports it, identify the encoding from the document itself, e.g.:

   - HTML 4:
     `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`
   - HTML 5:
     `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">`
   - CSS:
     `@charset "UTF-8";`
3. Declare the charset when linking the resource, e.g.:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   ```

   (This is actually deprecated.)

In practice, you can probably omit some of these steps. I'd say #1 is the most important.

Comment: Thanks that is the solution, I just see that i have setted charset iso-8859-1 on script tag for my utf-8 files.

Answer (score 0):

If you mix `encoding`, then you will face difficulty in future, especially if your pages contain different `locales`. So always use `UTF-8` encoding.

Also you can change `iso-8859-1` to `UTF-8`, without any changes in body as `UTF-8` contains all characters of any encoding.

Comment: UTF-8 is not a superset of ISO-8859-1. For instance, most accented letters use 2 bytes in UTF-8 and only 1 byte in ISO-8859-1. You're probably thinking of ASCII vs UTF-8.

Comment: What i mean by superset is that, UTF-8 contains all characters contained in iso-8859-1. In all UTF-8 contains all characters from every language.

Comment: I cant change the iso-8859-1 to UTF-8 because the webpage is printed by my c++ CGI and i can't update all sources of my cgi on utf-8 :S

Comment: @user2550754 - Correct :)